# Why is my image sequence appearing darker in the VSE than in the render output window?

Tags: rendering, light, video-sequence-editor

I'm having a weird problem with the VSE in Blender 2.90. I am rendering a night time scene using the physical atmosphere addon, with a very bright emissive object that passes through the sky. When I try to use the rendered image sequence in the VSE though, it appears much darker than it does in the viewport or when I replay the animation with ctrl+F11. I simply opened up a preset "video editing" workspace, then used shift+a to add the image sequence. I am experiencing the same problem with both cycles and EEVEE renders. Render format is the default PNG.

What might cause this behavior?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set View Transform to Standard(and not Filmic).

[image]

If you use the Video Editing template at start-up or through File - New - Video Editing it'll be set to Standard from the beginning.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While that did change the brightness a little bit, I discovered my problem was actually caused by my exposure setting - the physical atmosphere addon sets it to -6.0, and I did not realize that setting also affects VSE renders.